# I need records from my database according to primary ID.What's wrong in this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I need records from my database according to primary ID.
Already i have established a connection to my database with the variable $conn
And i want to echo the first row first column record from table named as allpages.

Here is my code but echoes nothing.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id=$_GET['id'];
}else{$id=1;};
$sqle="SELECT * FROM allpages WHERE id='$id'";
$res_data=mysqli_query($conn,$sqle);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)) {$first = 
$row[1];
$second = $row[2];
$third = $row[3];
$fourth= $row[4];};?>

 <?php echo $first;?>
```

Comment: if `id` really is a Primary Key then your query is only going to return one row so I'm not sure why you are looping.

Comment: You'll only have one result. Just use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data);` and reference `$row` directly.

Comment: It may be unnecessary but personally I can't see much harm in looping through a one row array

Comment: Thankyou.Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check your table, its having any records or not. Because i see your code and tested it, its working perfectly in my server and if you want only first record from database then why you are looping.

```
$sqle="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id'";
$res_data=mysqli_query($conn,$sqle);
$singleRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data) ;
echo $singleRow; //or print_r($singleRow);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hope this will help you and if you want single row record with all its column from db then use print_r instead of echo

Comment: Thankyou.You are right Actually primary ID number 1 was not present in my database.